# Javafx tableview on checkbox uncheck, disable button on same row but different column

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-tableview

Below image explains how I have populated my table:
[image]

As you can see, I need to disable the `Installments` column button once the `Collected` column checkbox of related row is unchecked and vise versa.

Here is my approach so far :

```
colected_column.setCellValueFactory((TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Member, CheckBox> param) -> {
        Member mRow = param.getValue(); // type objects contained within the TableView
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((ov, old_val, new_val) -> {

            // javafx.scene.control.Button typed ObservableValue returns as cell value
            Button button = installments_column.getCellData(mRow);
            button.setDisable(!new_val);
        });

      ...
      return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(checkBox);
}
```

But this approach does not meet the requirement, button stays enable all the time. Any help would be appreciable. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: nice pictures :) But as always: a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would be better. As to your problem: solve in the model realm, not in the view - you need a boolean that decides about disabled/selected (don't query the button state, just let both button and checkbox be driven by that property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put nodes in your item class. This way you ruin the main benefit of `TableView`: limiting the amount of nodes to the one it needs to display the content.

You should better use a `BooleanProperty` in your `Member` object, use `CheckBoxTableCell` to display the `CheckBox`es and use custom cells for the installments column:

```
TableColumn<Member, Boolean> colected_column = ...;

colected_column.setCellValueFactory((TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Member, Boolean> param) -> {
    Member mRow = param.getValue(); // type objects contained within the TableView
    return nRow.collectedProperty();
});
colected_column.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(colected_column));
```

```
TableColumn<Member, Boolean> installmentsColumn = ...;
installmentsColumn.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().collectedProperty());
installmentsColumn.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCell<Member, Boolean>() {

    private final Button button = new Button("View Info");

    {
        button.setOnAction(evt -> {
            Member member = (Member) getTableRow().getItem();

            // TODO: handle button click
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setGraphic(button);
            button.setDisable(!item);
        }
    }
});
```

```
public class Member {
    private final BooleanProperty collected = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);

    public void setCollected(boolean value) {
        collected.set(value);
    }

    public boolean isCollected() {
        return collected.get();
    }

    public BooleanProperty collectedProperty() {
        return collected;
    }

    ...
}
```